# Length of Strings regarding XOR operation for byte array

Tags: java, encryption, xor

I am creating an encryption algorithm and is to XOR two strings. While I know how to XOR the two strings the problem is the length. I have two byte arrays one for the plain text which is of a variable size and then the key which is of 56 bytes lets say. What I want to know is what is the correct method of XORing the two strings. Concatenate them into one String in Binary and XOR the two values? Have each byte array position XOR a concatenated Binary value of the key and such. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Milinda

Comment: Are you creating this out of academic curiosity, or to actually use?  Because if it's to actually use it, the correct way is to not.  Anyway, you'll want to convert everything to plain bytes, then loop through and xor everything.

Comment: Merely academic curiosity. If I loop it though if they size of the key and the plaintext is same some bytes will go unprocessed or unxored correct? Should I duplicate the key or plaintext values in order to match the highest length or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To encode just move through the array of bytes from the plain text, repeating the key as necessary with the mod % operator. Be sure to use the same character set at both ends.
Conceptually we're repeating the key like this, ignoring encoding.

```
hello world, there are sheep
secretsecretsecretsecretsecr
```

Encrypt

```
String plainText = "hello world, there are sheep";
Charset charSet = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
byte[] plainBytes = plainText.getBytes(charSet);
String key = "secret";
byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes(charSet);

byte[] cipherBytes = new byte[plainBytes.length];
for (int i = 0; i < plainBytes.length; i++) {

    cipherBytes[i] = (byte) (plainBytes[i] ^ keyBytes[i
            % keyBytes.length]);
}
String cipherText = new String(cipherBytes, charSet);
System.out.println(cipherText);
```

To decrypt just reverse the process.

```
// decode
for (int i = 0; i < cipherBytes.length; i++) {

    plainBytes[i] = (byte) (cipherBytes[i] ^ keyBytes[i
            % keyBytes.length]);
}
plainText = new String(plainBytes, charSet); // <= make sure same charset both ends
System.out.println(plainText);
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend *against* using this approach. 1) You're using ISO-8859-1 for the initial transformation, which will lose data for any characters not represented by that encoding. I would suggest using UTF-8 instead. 2) You're using the *platform default* encoding to convert the encrypted bytes to text. That's a bad idea in two ways - firstly, the platform default encoding can vary between platforms; secondly, you don't *have* encoded text. You have arbitrary binary data. Using the string constructor here is inappropriate, IMO. It can very easily lose data.

Comment: I am using UTF-8 instead so its ok on that front. What I was looking for was the keyBytes[i % keyBytes.length] part which helped.

Answer (score 2):

(As noted in comments, you shouldn't use this for anything real. Proper cryptography is incredibly hard to do properly from scratch - don't do it yourself, use existing implementations.)

There's no such concept as "XOR" when it comes to strings, really. XOR specifies the result given two *bits*, and text isn't made up of bits - it's made up of *characters*.

Now you *could* just take the Unicode representation of each character (an integer) and XOR those integers together - but the result may well be a sequence of integers which is *not* a valid Unicode representation of any valid string.

It's not clear that you're even thinking in the right way to start with - you talk about having strings, but also having 56 *bytes*. You may have an encoded *representation* of a string (e.g. the result of converting a string to UTF-8) but that's not the same thing.

If you've got two byte arrays, you can easily XOR those together - and perhaps cycle back to the start of one of them if it's shorter than the other, so that the result is always the same length as the longer array. However, even if both *inputs* are (say) UTF-8 encoded text, the result often won't be valid UTF-8 encoded text. If you *must* have the result in text form, I'd suggest using Base64 at that point - there's a [public domain base64 encoder](http://iharder.net/base64) which has a simple API.

Comment: Yes, sorry I did forget to mention that I am converting a string to UTF-8. Well my problem is that lets say the byte array length for the plaintext is 124 and that the length for the key array is 56. the problem is that since both values arent the same when xoring each bit some bits will not be XORed, how should I approach this?

Comment: @MilindaD: As I suggested in the answer, you could just loop back to the start of the key.